# Probability question (grid)

Tags: probability, random

Say I have a grid of 10x7. Every square of that grid is empty. Then, 20 squares, chosen at random, are filled (a square can only be filled once, so no duplicates allowed). What is the probability of getting at least one entire row of filled squares (in other words, the probability of 10 of those 20 "fillings" landing on the same row of 10 squares)?

Comment: Please show your work and we would be happy to give some hints.

Comment: I'm a bit too dumb and/or rusty on all things math. It's been ages since my last math class and I was just looking for a quick answer (although I would be interested in the method as well; I remember probability math being fun).

But what the hell, I'll share my monkey thoughts. The way I would start to approach it would be that the first "filling" could go anywhere, so it would be 70/70. The second should be on the same line, so the probability of it being in a correct place would be 9/69. The next ones would be 8/68, 7/67 and so forth. But the whole thing with 20 is where it gets messy...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Let us first get it wrong. There are $\binom{70}{20}$ ways to select $20$ squares, all equally likely.

A choice is favourable if some row is filled. Which row? It can be picked in $\binom{7}{1}$ ways. And then the rest of the squares can be filled in $\binom{60}{10}$ ways. That gives a total of $\binom{7}{1}\binom{60}{10}$ favourables.

*However*, we have **double-counted** every arrangement in which $2$ rows are filled. There are $\binom{7}{2}$ of these. Adjust.

Comment: I'm gonna have to admit that "math English" isn't my strongest quality, or at least it's an excuse for not following... I'm really rusty with all things math (it's been eight years since my last math class), so all this is pretty hard to grasp.

Comment: There are $\binom{70}{20}$ ways to choose squares to fill. There are $\binom{7}{1}\binom{60}{10}-\binom{7}{2}$ ways that we can have (at least) one entire row of filled squares. So the required probability is $\dfrac{\binom{7}{1}\binom{60}{10}-\binom{7}{2}}{\binom{70}{20}}$.

Comment: Thank you. I was about to ask if I understood it correctly (seems I did), but you beat me to it. Thanks :)